# Video does not load in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, web-applications, django-templates

I am trying to play video in my django built website but it is not playing.
Here is my setting code.

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static') ##lINKING THE STATIC FILES THAT IS CSS
STATICFILES_DIRS= [
       STATIC_DIR
 ]


MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/movies/'
```

*Views.py*

```
def Movie_detail(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Postmovie, pk=pk) ##EITHER gets specific object from primary key or return 404
    stuff_for_frontend = {'post': post}
    return render(request, 'Movie_Management_System/Movie_details.html',stuff_for_frontend) #render movie details
```

*Movie_details.html*

```
<br><br>
<video width='1000' controls> <!--video player using html-->
    <source src='{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ videofile }}' type='video/mp4'>
</video>
<br><br>
```

[image: Directory structure is like this]

Directory looks like

[image]

Comment: If any one can solve Please help me in debugging this problem

Comment: <source src='/media/movies/{{ stuff_for_frontend.videofile }}' type='video/mp4'> do this in your html, you are using different context from what you are passing into html

Comment: Raghav bro it did not work

Comment: If any one can give their view  please do help me